# How to define OpenGL extensions correctly?

Tags: opengl

I get OpenGL extensions using wglGetProcAddress. But on different machines it use different parameters: e.g. for using glDrawArrays I should call wglGetProcAddress with "glDrawArrays" or "glDrawArraysEXT". How todefine what to use?

Answer (score 2):

There's two pretty good OpenGL extension loading libraries out there - [GLee](http://elf-stone.com/glee.php) and [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). GLEW is currently more up to date that GLee. Even if you don't want to use either of them, they're both open source, so you could do worse than taking a peek on how they do things.

You may also want to check http://www.opengl.org/sdk/ which is a decent collection of OpenGL documentation online.

Comment: The OpenGL SDK also includes glload which is a very good extension loader.

Comment: Where? I can't find that one.

Comment: lol, it's the [first result](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glload.html) if you google 'glload'

Comment: I didn't google, I went to opengl.org/sdk/ and there's nothing there. Googling gives me "unofficial opengl sdk", which is a different thing.

Comment: oh yes sorry, it's not an 'official' sdk, that does not take away from how awesome it is.

Answer (score 1):

> "glDrawArrays" or "glDrawArraysEXT"

Both! Even if they're named similar, and more often than not procedure signature and token values are identical, *they are different* extensions, where details may be very well different.

It's ultimately up to the programmer to decide, which functions are used. And if a program uses an `…EXT` variant of a function, then this very function must be loaded even if there may be a `…ARB` or core function of same name; they may differ in signature and/or used tokens and state, so you can't mindlessly replace one for another.